# mod_rewrite clean urls with alphabets

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, clean-urls, clean-url

I was using mod rewrite to create clean urls. I have  urls like this :

```
http://www.sitename.com/viewcategory.php?id=262
```

I have rewritten successfully my url like this :

```
http://www.sitename.com/262
```

With the following mod_rewrite rule

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ viewcategory.php?id=$1
 RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ viewcategory.php?id=$1
```

What i want is to display the category name somthing like this:

```
http://www.sitename.com/categoryname
```

Please suggest me if there is a mistake in my rewrite rule or I need to do something else.
Thanks and regards.

Comment: Display category name how?

Comment: Means display a title of category not the number